# How to do AJAX call and PHP through submit button without form especially jQuery code

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I want to know more jQuery in database code how the submit button can pass value id?

> HTML button

```
<button id="primaryTextButton" value="submit" class="k-primary" style="float:right; padding: 5px 20px; border-radius: 4px;">Submit</button>
```

> Javascript that I want to make AJAX call

```
$(document).ready(function () {


    dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        transport: {
            read: {
                url:  "./getTest.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: function() {
                        return { 
                            method: "getTemplate",
                            positionTemplateID: document.getElementById('positionTemplateID').value,
                        //  hrsPositionID: dropdownlist.value(),
                        }
                    }
                },

            template: {
                url:  "./getTest.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: function () {
                        return {
                            method: "getTemplate",
                            employeeID: document.getElementById('employeeID').value,
                            propertyID: document.getElementById('propertyID').value,
                        }
                    },
                    complete: function (e) {  
                            $('#grid').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.read();
                          } 
                },
        },  
        schema: {
            model: {
            id: "positionTemplateID",
            }
        },

    });
```

> PHP in coding database which is query

```
function getTemplate() {
$positionTemplateID = (isset($_POST['positionTemplateID']) ? $_POST['positionTemplateID'] : '');
$hrsPositionID      = (isset($_POST['hrsPositionID']) ? $_POST['hrsPositionID'] : '');
$programID          = (isset($_POST['programID']) ? $_POST['programID'] : '');
$propertyID         = (isset($_POST['propertyID']) ? $_POST['propertyID'] : '');
$employeeID         = (isset($_POST['employeeID']));
```

> Output that I get

Here the link for demo: https://dojo.telerik.com/IYEvALiY/6

But, the submit button not function. I want to submit button is functioning to POST the selected node id in checkboxes into the database.

Comment: there is no Javascript here so why tag the question as such? An `INSERT` statement will not return a recordset which is what it appears you are trying to do with `$ehorsObj->FetchData` - all in all it is not clear what you mean

Comment: I'm sorry, I will update it again

Comment: Can you take a look again?

Comment: What do you mean with _But, the submit button not function_? where is your insert sql code? When you click your button i think you have to add a preventDefault() so you can submit it via ajax.

Comment: SQL code is at above- PHP in coding database which is query

Comment: well you need to attach an event handler function to the button. the event handler function should post the data to the server

Comment: Can you show some example here?

Answer (score 0):

This is how you normally make a button do an ajax call in jQuery

`$( "#primaryTextButton" ).click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault(); //so the page won't reload when you submit
  //make the ajax call
});`